# Как сделать горизонтальную гистограмму на Lattice

Tags: r

Какой параметр функции histogram из пакета Lattice отвечает за горизонтальную ориентацию гистограммы? Мне нужна горизонтальная гистограмма.

Answer (score 0):

Гистограмма - частный случай столбчатой диаграммы, а для нее есть параметр `horizontal = TRUE`.
См. http://myrcodes.blogspot.com/2014/10/barchart-lattice-package.html

Comment: Пробовал. Параметр horizontal для функции histogram не работает.